# How to increment to the next index of an array of objects in scope with ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I currently have a quiz app that uses an `ng-repeat` over an array of question objects. But, I do not want to repeat over all questions. I want to start off at the first index (one question at a time) , then submit the answer for that one quiz question and move on (increment) to the next quiz object / question. I only want one quiz question displayed to answer at a time.

I'm not sure the best way to achieve this in `Angular` though, after looking online, I'm still a bit confused.

here is my view:

---

.

```
  row(ng-app='Quiz')
      .row(ng-controller='QuestionsCtrl')
        .row
          .col-sm-12.col-md-12.top-label
            Answer Questions
        .row.row-format(ng-repeat='question in questions')
          %h1 {{question.text}}
          %div(ng-repeat = "answer in answers")
            %label
            %input(name = "answ" ng-model = "selectedAns" ng-value = "$index" type = "radio")
            {{answer}}
          %input(ng-click = "nextAndSubmit()" type = "button" value = "next")
```

---

My controller. Working on some other things that I may update shortly..

```
var QuestionsCtrl;

QuestionsCtrl = function($scope, Questions) {
  Questions.get().then(function(results) {
    return $scope.questions = results;
  });
    
  $scope.nextAndSubmit = function(){
    // I want to submit the answer, then move to 
    // the next quiz question once this function runs
  };

  return console.log("questions ctrl ", $scope.questions);
};

this.Quiz.controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionsCtrl);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more info and code, if possible. Show us what you want to achieve as opposed to what is currently happening. What is the quiz object if not the next question?

Comment: need more info. but if i understand correctly, you do not need to `ng-repeat`. Keep your questions in Array and keep populating the just one object depending upon answer.

Comment: Yeah. Working on giving a better explanation, but they can give any answer.  I want to display just one question at a time, then once they submit the answer on ng-click (for that one question), go to the next question until al questions are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Thought it was more difficult than it turned out to be.

```
var QuestionsCtrl;

QuestionsCtrl = function($scope, Questions) {
  $scope.questions = [];

  $scope.question_index = 0;


  Questions.get().then(function(results) {
    return $scope.questions = results;
  });


  $scope.nextAndSubmit = function(){
    if ($scope.question_index >= $scope.questions.length - 1) {
      $scope.question_index = 0;
    } else {
      $scope.question_index++;
    }
  };


};

this.Quiz.controller('QuestionsCtrl', QuestionsCtrl);
```

---

then in the view add an ng-if:

```
(ng-if = 'question_index == $index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Question Object: {
                  text: string, 
                  answers: [{},{},{},{}], 
                  answer: {}
                  }
```

You just need to populate `$scope.question`

Have a array of question objects. 
When clicking "Submit", depending on answer populate just one object.

Comment: How would that work?  Start w/ a specific index on $scope.question, then on ng-click = 'nextAndSubmit()' populate the next one? push?

Comment: @NoobSter dont do a push. you just store the answer in the main variable and then move on with the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use ng-repeat.

Rather, I would use ng-click to increment a value in your controller, and use that value as the index to your questions.

In your controller, something like:

```
myQuestion = $http.get(API Resource with question Primary Key)
```

In your html, something like:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="QuestionController as qCtrl>
  <span> {{ qCtrl.myQuestion.question }} </span>
  <span> ... </span>
  <button ng-click="qCtrl.myQuestion++">Click This Button</button>
</div>
```

I confess that I haven't tested this. And I'm pretty new to Angular.

Comment: this is the direction I'm wanting to go, but I'm also currently confused about how to implement exactly. I have .get() placing my questions in $scope.questions